# How to note the values across year?

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation

I'm working with time-series data that looks like this:

```
     cname year govstruct
6091 China 1960         3
6092 China 1961         3
6093 China 1962         3
6094 China 1963         3
6095 China 1964         3
6096 China 1965         3
6097 China 1966         3
6098 China 1967         3
6099 China 1968         3
6100 China 1969         3
6101 China 1970         3
6102 China 1971         3
6103 China 1972         3
6104 China 1973         3
6105 China 1974         3
6106 China 1975         3
6107 China 1976         3
6108 China 1977         3
6109 China 1978         3
6110 China 1979         3
6111 China 1980         3
6112 China 1981         3
6113 China 1982         3
6114 China 1983         1
6115 China 1984         1
6116 China 1985         1
6117 China 1986         1
6118 China 1987         1
6119 China 1988         1
6120 China 1989         1
6121 China 1990         1
6122 China 1991         1
6123 China 1992         1
6124 China 1993         1
6125 China 1994         1
6126 China 1995         1
6127 China 1996         1
6128 China 1997         1
6129 China 1998         1
6130 China 1999         1
6131 China 2000         1
6132 China 2001         1
6133 China 2002         1
6134 China 2003         1
6135 China 2004         1
6136 China 2005         1
6137 China 2006         3
6138 China 2007         3
6139 China 2008         3
6140 China 2009         3
6141 China 2010         3
6142 China 2011         3
6143 China 2012         3
```

I want to build a dataset that notes the range of dates that `govstruct` covers.

What I would like is a data set that notes the name of the country, the range of the years, and the value of the govstruct. Such that the final dataset looks like this:

```
cname    years  govstruct
China 1960-1982    3
China 1983-2005    1
China 2006-2012    3
```

Please note that I'll be looping over countries. So any code that can be fashioned to do so would be much appreciated.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `dplyr/data.table`  where we group by 'cname', and the `run-length-id` of 'govstruct', and `summarise` by `paste`ing the `range` of 'year'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(cname, grp = rleid(govstruct)) %>%
    summarise(govstructure = first(govstruct), 
         years = str_c(range(year), collapse="-"))  %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  cname govstructure years    
#  <chr>        <int> <chr>    
#1 China            3 1960-1982
#2 China            1 1983-2005
#3 China            3 2006-2012
```

Or we can also construct the `grp` based on comparing the adjacent elements

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(cname, grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(govstruct) != 0))) %>%
   summarise(govstructure = first(govstruct), 
         years = str_c(range(year), collapse="-"))
```

---

Or using `data.table` using the same method as in the `dplyr`.  i.e grouped by `rleid` of 'govstruct' and 'cname' `paste` the `range` of 'year'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[ , .(govstructure = first(govstruct),
      year = paste(range(year), collapse = "-")), 
      .(cname, grp = rleid(govstruct))][, grp := NULL][]
#  cname govstructure      year
#1: China            3 1960-1982
#2: China            1 1983-2005
#3: China            3 2006-2012
```

---

Or another option with `base R`

```
grp <- with(rle(df1$govstruct), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
aggregate(year ~ cname + grp, data = df1, 
      FUN = function(x) paste(range(x), collapse="-"))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(cname = c("China", "China", "China", "China", 
"China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", 
"China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", 
"China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", 
"China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", 
"China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", 
"China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", 
"China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China", "China"
), year = 1960:2012, govstruct = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-53L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` to `paste` the values of `first` and `last` `year` for each `cname` and run-length encoding value of `govstruct`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[ , .(year = paste(first(year), last(year), sep = "-"), 
           govstruct = first(govstruct)), .(cname, rleid(govstruct))]


#   cname rleid      year govstruct
#1: China     1 1960-1982         3
#2: China     2 1983-2005         1
#3: China     3 2006-2012         3
```